# Sorting of an array without using array.sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am not getting output of this code i dont understand what is the error in this code can anyone help? I am using ide and the error that it shows is not understandable by me .I am pasting my code below so that you could know

```
class sort_basic
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) 
        {
            int[] myInt=new int[]{20,100,69,4};

            for(int a=0;a<myInt.length;a++)
            {
                for(int b=a;b<myInt.length;b++)
                {
                    if(myInt[a]>myInt[b])
                    {
                        int temp;
                        temp=myInt[a];
                        myInt[a]=myInt[b];
                        myInt[b]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Sorted Array is:");
            for(int i=0;i<myInt.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(myInt[a]);
            }
        }
    }
```

For more understanding i am also pasting the o/p here:
    24: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.println(myInt[a]);
                                         ^
      symbol:   variable a
      location: class sort_basic
      1 error

Comment: Wouldn't it help if you posted the error?

Comment: Read about variable scope.

Comment: _"the error that it shows is not understandable by me"_ then post the errors here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        for(int i=0;i<myInt.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(myInt[a]);
//                                   ^ Wrong variable
        }
```

You typed `a` instead of `i`.

Comment: because i have print myint[a] variable i is just for looping